# How to return string provided in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, string, parameters, return

In C#, Java, or any language I use, this kind of code

```
static void Main()
{
    printMe("myself");
}
static void printMe(string v)
{
    WriteLine(v);
}
```

or similar codes... now, I'd like to do something like that in Javascript and HTML...

Javascript:

```
function showDiv(strMe){
    document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = '<p>' & strMe & '</p>';
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="something"></div>
<a href="#" onClick="showDiv('Hello World!')">Click Me!</a>
```

so, when I click the "Click Me!" button, a message "Hello World!" will appear above it.
Probably, there could be something of a duplicate of this kind of question, but I'll try to ask since I don't get the situations of others. Thank you very much!

Comment: Use + instead of & to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 1):

Replace those `&` with `+`. The concatenation character of strings in JS is `+` not `&`.

TIP: Always look out for the console(Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome) when working with JS.

[<kbd>Demo.</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/q8yum1h9/)

Comment: What the? I never thought of that! -_- Thank you very much! It works now... hahaha... I've gain new knowledge of trying every other options now... ^_^

Comment: @Pat-kunTeruel If you like my answer, upvote it, and it solves your problem, accept it.

Comment: I want to, but I can't... I don't have enough points to upvote, sorry... :)

Comment: It's called the [*Addition Operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1), but if one of the operands is a string, it does concatenation. :-)

Comment: @Pat-kunTeruel Accept atleat? :P

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation in JS is "+" NOT "&" your code should read:

```
function showDiv(strMe){
   document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = '<p>' + strMe + '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="something"></div>
<a href="#" onClick="showDiv('Hello World!')">Click Me!</a>
</body>
</html>

function showDiv(strMe){
   document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = '<p>' + strMe + '</p>';
}
```

http://jsbin.com/xijaqizufi/1/edit